# divide django form fields to two divs

Tags: html, django, django-forms

hi guys i have a form with a checkbox that if checked needs to display an additional bunch of fields, is it possible to tell the form to wrap some fields in one div and the rest in another div? this way I can play around client-side with javascript, I also want to do it client-side for styling purposes,
any help will be greatly appreciated
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [render fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) and add any styles you like.

```py
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}">Email subject:</label>
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.message.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.message.id_for_label }}">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.message }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.sender.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.sender.id_for_label }}">Your email address:</label>
    {{ form.sender }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.cc_myself.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.cc_myself.id_for_label }}">CC yourself?</label>
    {{ form.cc_myself }}
</div>
```

Also, check out [this neat article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html) on the subject.